# Logical question: Given corners, find Center of Quadrilateral?

Tags: c#, java, c++, logic

Given the cordinates of all corners of a quadrilateral, how can the cordinates of its center be found?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at triangles, there are [different definitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_center) of what "the center" means. I suspect that for quadrilaterals the meaning of "the center" is equally ambiguous. So what definition of "center" do you mean?

Comment: By center is mean 'a point which is equidistant from corners.'

Comment: @Azoduis, there is no such points for most quadrilaterals. Think of it this way: a circle is defined by three points. The center of the circle is equidistant to those points. Make a quadrilateral by adding any point not in the circle to your three points. You have a quad where one point is not at the same distance from the "center" as the others...

Comment: @juanchopanza: but rectangle and squares have such centers. and they are quadrilateral too.

Comment: @Azodious Yes, but they are a special family of quadrilaterals (for which my first recipe also works).

Comment: @Azodious but you asked about quadrilaterals in general, and not just rectangles and squares. If you need it only for rectangles and squares, then say so.

Comment: [What do you want it for?](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal) And this has nothing to do with programming anyway (and you certainly aren't programming in C#, Java, and C++ at the same time), so closing as off-topic.

Comment: http://www.geometry.online02.com/Dynamic%20Worksheets/Lesson_4_6.html

Comment: [xna quest for centroid of polygon](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2009/09/xna-quest-for-centroid-of-polygon.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Origin = x=0,y=0

a(0,0)   b(10,0)

c(0,5)   d(10,5)

```
a+(b-a/2)=5
a+(c-a/2)=2.5
```

centre co-ordinate = 5,2.5

or `dx-ax/2=5`
   `dy-ay/2=2.5`

with those formulas it wouldn't matter if the sides were uneven the centre can always be calculated.

Regards
Ray

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this is only correct IF you are working with a rectangle (or square) because it does not take into account all 4 corners. For example in a dart or kite point-d is not the same distance from points c & b as a is.  This site goes into some explanation of why it is not such an easy answer: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/EMT668.Folders.F97/Patterson/EMT%20669/centroid%20of%20quad/Centroid.html

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are talking about the centroid or center of masses. In a quadrilateral there are two general ways of getting the coordinates:

1. Intersection point of the two bimedians (A bimedian is the line joining the center points of two opposing sides).
2. The midpoint of the line joining the midpoints of both diagonals of the quadrilateral.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your shape is defined by a piecewise continuous curve you can do numerical integration using Gaussian quadrature of a [contour integral for the center of mass](http://shuisman.com/?p=359).  This is the most general algorithm for 2D planar shapes.  It'll even work for shapes with holes inside.

You get the contour integral using [Green's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensTheorem.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also cut up the quadrilateral in two triangles, take their centre and find the centre between them.

Doesn't really change anything but it might be easier to think about (ps. I don't say this would yield a particularly better solution).